# After update from Magento 2.1 to 2.2.5, categories are not displayed because is_active is missing

Tags: magento-2.2.5, debugging

After an update to 2.2.5 it turned out, that all categories are not shown anymore.

Debugging the issue revealed, that `$category->isActive()` just is null. Debugging further showed that `catalog_category_int` does not have any entries for the attribute is_active (in my case attribute_id = 46)